# How to upload a folder to s3 through the command line?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I've tried to copy my current folder to the bucket:

```
aws s3 cp path s3://bucket/NewFolder
```

but when I sync again using

```
aws s3 sync s3://bucket/NewFolder/ /home/test
```

all I get is an empty folder meaning that my folder was not copied in the first place.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Question may be appropriate for [Server fault](http://serverfault.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Copy all content from the current folder, but not the folder itself:**

For example, I am copying all the content from data folder which is located under NewFolder, with tgsbucket my bucket:
`aws s3 cp data s3://tgsbucket --recursive`

**Copy the local folder:**

Specify folder name after bucket name:
`aws s3 cp data s3://tgsbucket/data --recursive`

Answer (score 7):

You can use this to copy a whole folder to S3:

```
aws s3 cp --recursive path s3://bucket/NewFolder
```

Or, sync the local folder to S3:

```
aws s3 sync path s3://bucket/NewFolder/
```